# Calculate month on month change in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I have a data set that records revenue by member, by month, by product. I can sum the revenue by member like so:

```
select sum(revenue), member, month from member_revenue group by member, month
```

I want to calculate the month on month change is revenue by member, ideally without having to call the data in the table for a second time.

Comment: what version of Oracle ?

Comment: Oracle SQL developer 4.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `lag()`:

```
select member, month, sum(revenue) as this_month_revenue,
       lag(sum(revenue)) over (partition by member order by month) as last_month_revenue
from member_revenue
group by member, month;
```

Note:  This assumes that all months have revenue.  `LAG()` gets the revenue from the preceding row, even if it is not the preceding month.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the query you already have as an inner query and wrap it with an outer query that subtracts the previous month revenue from each month by using the `lag` window function:

```
SELECT member, 
       month, 
       month_revenue,
       month_revenue - 
       LAG(month_revenue) OVER (PARTITION BY member
                                ORDER BY month ASC) AS revenue_change
FROM   (SELECT   member, month, SUM(revenue) AS month_revenue
        FROM     member_revenue
        GROUP BY member, month) t
```

Comment: This is great, thanks! Slight update is that I believe 'month' needs to be omitted from the 'partition by' statement.

Comment: @JamieEdgecombe that is correct, of course. How embarrassing. Edited and fixed.